# multiple categories classification - good idea to use a different set of negative samples for each category?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification

We have a classifier that classifies websites into one-of 50 categories.

The classic approach is to build 50 two-class classifiers (as in here: [nlp](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-text-classification-1.html)). There's a *single* big tagged learning corpus, and we train each classifier with positive samples from its category, and negative samples from all other categories.

Is it a good idea to decouple completely and hold for each category a set of positive *and* negative samples?

This will enable us:

- It will be very easy for us to gather and add more negative samples (we just take random sites)
- Currently, adding of a 51st new category is a very hard process, as the older categories were trained a long time ago, so the new 51st classifier gets confused by new samples having temporal properties that are different from the old samples - and the other option of refreshing all 51 categories is very expensive. If we'll decouple, we can leave the current 50 classifiers intact and just add a new one, with new positive and negative samples!

Question: can you see something wrong with this idea? If so, can you point me to literature/research in this direction? If not, where's the bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that every site should belong to one of the 50 categories, then your initial idea sounds better. However, when you have that many categories, binary classifiers are not always the best solution because you have to each take each category and make it a positive class and all other categories a negative class (one vs. all), or you take all pairs of categories and and train your classifier for each pair. Either way, you have to decide the category for a testing point by running all the classifiers post-processing the results.

There are good classifiers that can handle as many categories as you want with a single classifier. Random forests are a good example, they work very well in practice especially if your features are all either numeric or symbolic with only a few possible values. And they are fast to train and run on testing data.

Comment: thanks, but the approach you're offering is tightly coupling all 50 categories, making adding a 51st category extremely hard. If the same training set is shared by all categories, then adding a new one requires refreshing all other 50. The single classifier suggestion makes it even more coupled - adding a new category might seriously damage performance of an old category